# Public IP for AWS Aurora possible or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-aurora-serverless

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.html#aurora-serverless.limitations) states that Aurora Serverless DB cannot have a public IP Address:

> You can't give an Aurora Serverless DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless DB cluster only from within a virtual private cloud (VPC) based on the Amazon VPC service.

However, this confuses me as I was just able to set "Public accessibility" to "Yes". I was also able to connect to the database outside the VPC using the endpoint specified.

[image]

Am I misunderstanding the limitations (Public IP)? Or is this something that was made possible just recently?

Thank you!

Comment: It looks like public availability is a recent addition. It wasn't possible a few months ago when I looked at it, but it was a stated goal. Based on the screenshot it doesn't look like there's an IP assigned to you but rather a host name. You likely need to use the host name in your request, not the IP it resolves to (guessing, but fairly sure).

Comment: Yes! I used the hostname and it worked perfectly. Quite weird that there's no official announcement on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part you quoted mentions Aurora **Serverless** - this is different to the Aurora you are using in your picture.

Serverless is only available inside VPC as your quote states - Standard Aurora can be made publicly accessible, although generally it's better practice to restrict access to inside VPC only.